# How can I create a pie/gauge chart showing the lines between the bar gaps with recharts?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, pie-chart, recharts

I would like to create a semi circle chart showing both the bars information and the information between the bar gaps.

Today the chart looks like this:

[stability_graph_before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIyMm.png)

But I would like to have something like:

[stability_graph_after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGkRQ.png)

It's possible to do this using recharts lib?